# what does the following type casting do in C?

Tags: c, casting

I have a question about type casting in C:

```
void *buffer;

(int *)((int)buffer);
```

what is this type casting doing? and what does the `((int)buffer)` doing?

Comment: It looks pointless. It's almost the same as `(int*)buffer`, just less correct.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ah.  Like so many things in programming, you think you're seeing something interesting, when it actually isn't.

Comment: If anything, it truncates the pointer to the lower 32-bits. That's even worse than...

Comment: you can use something like that to make sure that you are running on a 32bit machine, and crash otherwise :P

Comment: @Elazar: Except that doesn't *guarantee* that you'll crash. If the converted pointer happens to fit in 32 bits, it could "work".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you are on a Linux/x86-64 computer like mine. Then pointers are 64 bits and `int` is 32 bits wide.

So, the `buffer` variable has been initialized to some location; Perhaps 0x7fff4ec52020 (which could be the address of some local variable, perhaps inside `main`).

The cast `(int)buffer` gives you an int, probably the least significant 32 bits, i.e. 0x4ec52020

You are casting again with `(int*)((int)buffer)`, which gives you the bogus address 0x000000004ec52020 which does not point into valid memory. If you dereference that bogus pointer, you'll very probably get a SIGSEGV.

So on some machines (notably mine) `(int *)((int)buffer)` is *not the same* as `(int*)buffer`;

Fortunately, as a *statement*, `(int *)((int)buffer);` has no visible side effect and will be optimized (by "removing" it) by the compiler (if you ask it to optimize).

So such code is a huge mistake (could become an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), e.g. if you dereference that pointer). If the original coder really intended the weird semantics described here, he should add a comment (and such code is unportable)!

Perhaps `#include`-ing `<stdint.h>` and using [`intptr_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) or `uintptr_t` could make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what the C Standard has to say. On page 55 of the last freely published version of the C11 standard http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf we have

> 5 An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> 6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

What does this mean in your example?  Section 6 says that the cast `(int)buffer` will compile, but if the integer is not big enough to hold the pointer (which is likely on 64-bit machines), the result is undefined.  The final `(int*)` casts back to a pointer.

Section 5 says that if the integer *was* big enough to hold the intermediate result, the result is exactly the same as just casting to (int*) from the outset.

In short the cast `(int)` is at best useless and at worst causes the pointer value to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

In straight C code this is pointless because conversions to and from `void*` are implicit.  The following would compile just fine

```
int* p = buffer;
```

Worse though is this code potentially introduces errors.  Consider the case of a 64 bit platform.  The conversion to `int` will truncate the pointer to 32 bits and then assign it to an `int*`.  This will cause the pointer value to be truncated and certainly lead to errors.

Comment: @user2131316 it just tells the C compiler to treat address as an `int` value in the resulting expression

Comment: @user2131316: It *converts* the pointer value from type `void*` to type `int`. This is likely to copy the representation of the pointer (or of its last 32 bits, depending on `sizeof (int)` into an `int`, but the C language standard merely *suggests* that "The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment." The result of the conversion is implementation-defined, and may or may not be meaningful. It's a silly thing to do.

Comment: while the code: char * p; (int *)p tells the C compiler to treat address as an int value, right? So the (int)buffer does the same? then it is not necessary to do it twice

Comment: Not quite: The code `char *p; (int *)p` tells the C compiler to treat the value of `p`, which is of type pointer-to-char, as though it were of type `pointer-to-int`. With appropriate conversions, as necessary.